# How to use Craft CMS?

Tags: craft3

I've manage to install Craft CMS with command line, I've the message "installed craft successfully" so I guess it worked, plus my database has been completely populated.
But then, how do we access the CMS lol ?
I've installed it at localhost/craftcms/ but then I don't know where I have to go to use the tool.
I use wamp ( on Windows of course).
Thanks for all, and sorry for my question that I'm sure is stupid but I can't find an answer

Comment: Try going to http://localhost/craftcms/index.php?p=admin

Answer (score 1):

The default URL to access Craft is `/admin`.

Note also this can be changed to anything you like using the `cpTrigger` [config variable](https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/config/config-settings.html#cptrigger).

Comment: When I go to http://localhost/craft/admin I get The requested URL /craft/admin was not found on this server..

Comment: When I go to http://localhost/craft/admin I get The requested URL /craft/admin was not found on this server..

Comment: Try going to localhost/craft/web/admin

Answer (score 1):

Make sure WAMP Document root is pointing to your 'Web' folder in the Craft install or whatever you might have changed it to.